# Let my class return array when doing Array.from

Tags: javascript, class, prototypal-inheritance

I have a  PriorityQueue class, and it has many methods, such as add, peak, changePriority etc. So to instantiate the class we have:

```
let priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue();
```

To add something to a PriorityQueue instance, I can do something like this:

```
priorityQueue.add(10, 1);
priorityQueue.add(100, 0);
priorityQueue.add(200, 0);
```

My question is how can we do

```
Array.from(priorityQueue)
```

so that returns `[100, 200, 10]`?

Here is my complete code:

```js
class QElement { 
    constructor(element, priority) 
    { 
        this.element = element; 
        this.priority = priority; 
    } 
} 
  
class PriorityQueue extends Array{ 
  
    // An array is used to implement priority 
    constructor() 
    { 
        super()
        this.items = []; 
    } 
    add(value, priority) 
    { 
        // creating object from queue element 
        var qElement = new QElement(value, priority); 
        var contain = false; 
      
        // iterating through the entire 
        // item array to add element at the 
        // correct location of the Queue 
        for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) { 
            if (this.items[i].priority > qElement.priority) { 
                // Once the correct location is found it is 
                // enqueued 
                this.items.splice(i, 0, qElement); 
                contain = true; 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
      
        // if the element have the highest priority 
        // it is added at the end of the queue 
        if (!contain) { 
            this.items.push(qElement); 
        } 
    }
    
    poll() 
    { 
        // return the dequeued element 
        // and remove it. 
        // if the queue is empty 
        // returns Underflow 
        if (this.isEmpty()) 
            return "Underflow"; 
        return this.items.shift(); 
    } 
    
    peak() 
    { 
        // returns the highest priority element 
        // in the Priority queue without removing it. 
        if (this.isEmpty()) 
            return "No elements in Queue"; 
        return this.items[0]; 
    } 
    
    rear() 
    { 
        // returns the lowest priorty 
        // element of the queue 
        if (this.isEmpty()) 
            return "No elements in Queue"; 
        return this.items[this.items.length - 1]; 
    }
    
    printPQueue() 
    { 
        var str = ""; 
        for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) 
            str += this.items[i].element + " "; 
        return str; 
    } 
}

var priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue();

priorityQueue.add(10, 1);
priorityQueue.add(100, 0);
priorityQueue.add(200, 0);
priorityQueue.printPQueue()
let ppp = Array.from(priorityQueue)
console.log(ppp)
```

This should return `[100, 200, 10]`, but it returned [], an empty array.

I have to strictly use `Array.from`. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Still not able to get list of arrays

Comment: What does `getName` and `getAge` have to do with the explanation in the first part of your question. The two code blocks seem to be about two entirely different implementations.

Comment: I have now added the exact code, the previous one was a example of the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator).

In the snippet below I have omitted any priority queue logic, and just used `sort` to demonstrate how that generator can be used:

```js
class PriorityQueue {
    constructor() {
        this.arr = [];
    }
    add(data, priority) {
        this.arr.push({ data, priority });
    }
    * [Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield * [...this.arr].sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority).map(a => a.data);
    }
};

let priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue();
priorityQueue.add(10, 1);
priorityQueue.add(100, 0);
priorityQueue.add(200, 0);
console.log(Array.from(priorityQueue));
```

### After edit

The code you added to the question shows a mistake. Although you extend `Array`, you never make use of the Array capabilities of your instance. Your code continues as if it doesn't inherit those and instead creates an array *property* called `items`. It is to be expected when you push items to the `items` property that the `this` object will remain an empty array. If you want to use `extends` then you should have calls like `this.push(value)`, `this.pop()` and `this.splice(.....)` somewhere.